# Multiple bootstrap sliders using asp:repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, slider, repeater

I have to use multiple bootstrap carousel in single page, using the asp repeater control but it doesn't work, it just show one slider on the page

Here is the html and asp code

---

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">
            <!-- Carousel items -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="row">
                        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Slider1">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <a target="_blank" href="<%# Eval("URL") %>">
                                            <img class="caption" src="../Includes/gaceta/<%# Eval("Titulo") %>/files/res/pages/page_0000.jpg" alt="<%# Eval("Titulo") %>" width="188" height="222" /></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </div>
                    <!--.row-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--.carousel-inner-->
            <a data-slide="prev" href="#Carousel" class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
            <a data-slide="next" href="#Carousel" class="right carousel-control">›</a>
        </div>
        <!--.Carousel-->
    </div>


    <hr />
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="Carousel2" class="carousel slide">
            <!-- Carousel items -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="row">
                       <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Slider2">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <a target="_blank" href="<%# Eval("URL") %>">
                                            <img class="caption" src="../Includes/gaceta/<%# Eval("Titulo") %>/files/res/pages/page_0000.jpg" alt="<%# Eval("Titulo") %>" width="188" height="222" /></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </div>
                    <!--.row-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--.carousel-inner-->
            <a data-slide="prev" href="#Folletos" class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
            <a data-slide="next" href="#Folletos" class="right carousel-control">›</a>
        </div>
        <!--.Carousel-->
```

the javascript

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Carousel').carousel('pause');
    $('#Carousel2').carousel('pause');

    $("div.item:first").addClass("active");
});
```

and the methods to bind the repeater

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
       BindSlider1(5);
       BindSlider2(1);
    }


    protected void BindSlider1(int Ubicacion)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = Conexion.Conecta())
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SelGacetaUbicacion", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UBICACION", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Ubicacion;
                con.Open();
                Slider1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                Slider1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void BindSlider2(int Ubicacion)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = Conexion.Conecta())
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SelGacetaUbicacion", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UBICACION", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Ubicacion;
                con.Open();
                Slider2.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                Slider2.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the href #Folletos be #Carousel2?

Comment: Thanks, but i changed and still does't work, the second slider doesn't show

Comment: Have you verified that both carousels sql queries returns data? have you verified if there is any javascript errors thrown in the browser console?

Comment: store procedure its fine, it returns the correct data and the javascript theres no errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code, and found this issues:

1- Review how to build the carousel markup depending on which version of bootstrap you are using. I tried with Bootstrap v3.1.0 and had to change parts of your markup. Refer to [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) or [this sample](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/).
For instance, `<div class="item">` should be placed inside your repeater, and should have a `<div class="container">` immediatly inside of it.

2- You are not initializing correctly both carousels from jquery, do something like this to correct it:

```
$("#Carousel div.item:first").addClass("active");
$("#Carousel2 div.item:first").addClass("active");
```